# What is the best configuration for dual boot Ubuntu and Windows on SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

Currently I have a laptop Asus A43S with 8GB RAM, HDD 500GB, dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 10 (upgraded from Windows 7). The HDD has 4 partitions. They are Windows 10 (162GB NTFS), Ubuntu (104GB ext4), Swap (6.4GB) and Data (228GB NTFS). Everything work fine.

I am planning to replace the HDD with SSD (Samsung 850 EVO 250GB) to speed up many things and use the HDD as a storage (with HDD caddy). It's been ordered actually. Hope I'll receive it today. I still want to use the dual boot but now for Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 10 (I have Windows 7 DVD installer if I have to fresh install the Windows then upgrade it to Windows 10).

I've read many QAs and articles about the dual boot on SSD. But I think I need to ask some more specific questions. For the last few years, I use Ubuntu more than windows. May be I spend 90% my work time on Ubuntu. As a web & mobile developer (especially for the backend), I installed and use many software and text editor. My web app reside in /var/www/ directory (Ubuntu) and C:\xampp (Windows). I want to ask the best configuration for this new SSD:

1. I want to divide the SSD to be just two partitions. its for Windows and Ubuntu. What is the best size for them? I think it would be larger for Ubuntu because I use it much but with the SSD speed may be I'd also back to Windows someday or may be back and forth between them. May be 130GB for ubuntu and 120GB for windows. but I read Samsung 850 EVO recommend to use over-provisioning that would take SSD space 10% (it'd be take 25GB on my case).
2. I read some ubuntu directories like /home and /var should be put in HDD. Currently my HDD already has /home and /var directory. If I use the SSD then install Ubuntu 14.04, can I just link to the directories?
3. I use many hibernate mode and really need it because I open many software/app at once and hate to open it one by one. sometimes I use it for a week or more or until the ubuntu update force me to restart after installing the linux kernel. Should I just put the swap partition on SSD? or put it on the SSD and HDD?
4. I think I'll fresh install the OSs (Ubuntu and Windows) on the SSD but is it possible (or is it better) to just clone the current OSs on the HDD then install them back on the SSD?

Thank you in advance. I hope my questions are clear. Sorry for my english. I'm not native.